# PHP replace currency in a string

Tags: php, regex, number-formatting

I am trying to format a string in order to get a number. I have tried different methods however, when I try to remove the `€` symbol I get a series of numbers instead. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sn_get_full_price = "€12.000,0";
$sn_get_full_price_no_comma = preg_replace('/^([^,]*).*$/', '$1',$sn_get_full_price);
$sn_get_n_price = preg_replace('/[^\d,\.]/', '',$sn_get_full_price_no_comma);
```

the result I have is `836412.000` instead of `12000`.

Also there is a way to to this with one line of code?

Comment: Not reproducible - https://3v4l.org/JZYYQ

Comment: I get `12.000` using this exact code

Comment: thats strange . why the € symbol is replaced with 8364? I am using wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your real string is `"&#8364;12.000,0"` with the € symbol written as an html entity (display the source code of your html page to be convinced).

To solve that you can use:

```
echo str_replace(['&#8364;', ',0'], '', $yourstring);
```

You can also use your actual code, except that you have to convert the entities before (with [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)) and to add the `u` modifier to your patterns (in particular the second one).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sn_get_full_price = "€12.000,0";
$sn_get_full_price_no_comma = preg_replace('/[^0-9]|[^,]*$/m', '' ,$sn_get_full_price);
```

This regex returns 12000.

It removes everything that is non-numeric ([^0-9]) as well as all signs after the decimal-comma ([^,]*$).